# The infinite loop when using [super peformSelector:] method

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a infinite loop problem when I using the method `[super performSelector:@selector(aMethod)]` in a SubClass, which in detail like this:

I have a BaseClass

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
//- (void) aMethod:(NSString *) aString;
@end

@implementation Parent
- (void) aMethod:(NSString *) aString
{
  NSLog(@"Base");
}
@end
```

and a SubClass

```
@interface SubClass :BaseClass
- (void) aMethod:(NSString *) aString;
@end

@implementation Parent
- (void) aMethod:(NSString *) aString
{
  [super performSelector:@selector(aMethod:) withObject:nil];
  NSLog(@"Sub");
}
@end
```

when I send the instance `subClass` of `SubClass` the message `[subClass aMethod]`, there is a  infinite loop problem that calling `[subClass aMethod:]` & `[super performSelector:]` Alternately.

Can anybody tell me why it happened?
What I only knew is that the `[super performSelector:]` will use `objc_msgSendSuper` to send a message, but why this invocation caused a infinite loop problem makes me crazy.

Comment: Just call [super aMethod]? Why are you calling performSelector?  Unless you override performSelector, calling [self perform..] and [super perform..] will not be functionally different.

Comment: @ErikKerber That should definitely be an answer.

Comment: `@implementation Parent`? shouldn't that be `@implementation BaseClass` and `@implementation SubClass`? also, shouldn't `@interface SubClass : NSObject` be `@interface SubClass : BaseClass`? Is `NSLog(@"Base");` even being called? I think `NSLog(@"Sub");` is going infinite because your structure is calling it recursively.

Comment: @ Erik Kerber I use `performSelector` because `aMethod` is a private aMethod in `BaseClass`. I want to override the private method in `SubClass` at the begin.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `objc_msgSendSuper()` instead of `[super performSelector:]`.

**Edit:** To clarify, the `performSelector:` method is actually implemented all the way up in `NSObject`, so it does not matter if you call it on `self` or `super`, the implementation goes to the overridden implementation of `aMethod`.

---

```
@interface BaseClass ()
- (void) aMethod:(NSString *) aString;
@end
```

Best option is to add a class extension you your subclass .m file. Now your subclass is aware of the method, and you can call `[super aMethod:];`.

Comment: But why `[super performSelector:]` doesn't work as I expected. I think `NSLog(@"Base")` will be invoked

Comment: Because the `performSelector:` method is actually implemented all the way up in `NSObject`, so it does not matter if you call it on `self` or `super`, the implementation goes to the overridden implementation of `aMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

`Subclass` is declared a subclass of `NSObject`, which doesn't implement `aMethod`.  Also, both `@implementation` directives refer to `Parent`, which is undefined as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Actually `SubClass` is a subClass of `BaseClass`

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm assuming there's a typo in your post and that there are 2 classes, BaseClass and SubClass, and that Subclass subclasses BaseClass.

Unless you override performSelector in SubClass, then [super performWithSelector:] will be functionally equivalent to calling [self performWithSelector:].

In this case, you should just call [super aMethod] instead.

Comment: I use performSelector because aMethod is a private aMethod in BaseClass. I want to override the private method in SubClass at the begin.

Comment: Are you sure it's "private"? Method's can't be private in Objective-C. You can "hide" them by putting them in class extensions, but you haven't done that.

Comment: I think I can't invoke `aMethod` of `BaseClass` out of the `BaseClass`, I haven't declare it in the header file of `BaseClass`. Is it "private" now? So I can just use `performSelector` to invoke this method of `BaseClass`.

Comment: It really depends how much of the code you wrote above matches the code you've implemented.  If you've declared both the interface and the implementation in the .m file, then how does SubClass know what it's inheriting from?  It really seems like the effect you're going after is a "protected" method, which is unfortunately in my opinion one of the bigger features I'd like to see in Obj-C.  Alas, you won't be able to achieve what you wish without exposing your base method to the rest of the world.  Think encapsulation over inheritance, if it helps. @panbabybaby

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are making `super` call `-performSelector:withObject:`, not the method you pass in. Since I assume none of your objects implement `-performSelector:withObject:` that call reaches all the way down to the NSObject implementation, which is the same as if you did on `super` or `self`.

What I expect you are trying to do is call `[super aMethod:anObject];`. If you are trying to do it with a variable selector, you must use the Objective C runtime, but I would strongly suggest you reexamine your goals. In 5 years of iOS development, I've never had the need to do that.